# Why do I get when I try to use getDatasource from dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a dependency jar that has the following...

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:datasource.properties")
public class DatasourceConfig {
    ...
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        try {
            PoolDataSource ds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
            ds.setConnectionFactoryClassName(OracleDataSource.class.getName());
            ...
            return ds;
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            logger.error(throwables);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I import this JAR using maven but then when I run `java -cp 'JAR_LOCATION:ETC' pkg.Application` I get...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Answer (score 0):

Are you scanning packages as well somewhere in the code?
If not try adding

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.food.bar") <---
@PropertySource("classpath:datasource.properties")
public class DatasourceConfig {
```

Comment: There are better ways if you are writing library. You can use @Import annotation to import Configuration class or use spring.factories.xml